# What does "there is no" mean in this sentence from my notes?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

I read in my book,

[image]

I ran into a challenge with the combination of words "there is no". Does it mean "no any line", or just one line? Is it possible to make it simpler for me?

Comment: It means "a good linear vertical separator of the training data _does not exist_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, "is", the be-verb, denotes the existence of something as opposed to its state, as in,

> Five students are here in the class.

Let us consider the relevant part of the original sentence,

> there is no good linear vertical separator of the training data.

In simpler terms (without adjectives), it is,

> there is no separator of the data.

At its core, the clause is a negative one that conveys that **a separator of the data does not exist**. You could also say, "**No separator is there of the training data.**" Therefore, "there is no", in this context, means "there exists no".